# Live Streaming for f4m Format

Tags: html, flash, live-streaming

How to play f4m live urls using HTML? I have played m3u8 format it working fine but f4m is not playing in HTML, my sample url will be,

[http://localhost.live-s.cdn.bitgravity.com/cdn-live/*definst*/localchannel/live/manifest.f4m](http://localhost.live-s.cdn.bitgravity.com/cdn-live/_definst_/localchannel/live/manifest.f4m)

Anyone please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why can't the same media files listed within **f4m** just be listed within **m3u8**? Is it MP4 data?

Comment: I can only suggest to use the OSFM (Open source media framework) - you build the player once (a player template is included) and it can play all known formats - static, live, encrypted, you name it. Some formats require plugins but they are really easy to include.

Comment: Thanks Philarmon, Can u send me the sample code, it will be useful to refer

Comment: @RanjithKumar ... Get the template player from here : [**Strobe Media Playback**](https://github.com/denivip/StrobeMediaPlayback). Also maybe this will help you [**about OSMF**](https://dzone.com/refcardz/getting-started-web-video). Flash plugin must be enabled for browser.